# Most optimal way to search through a Map

Tags: java, list, search, optimization, hashmap

I have a Map (lets say of people, per example) like this:

```
public Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And I want to search through this map filtering by name.
I have this code, but I am curious if there is a more optimal or elegant way to do it.

```
public ArrayList<Person> searchByName(String query) {
    ArrayList<Person> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : this.personMap.entrySet()) {
        Person person = entry.getValue();
        String name = entry.getValue().getName();
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
            listOfPeople.add(person);
        }
    }
    if (listOfPeople.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This data doesn't appear on the Map");
    }
    return listOfPeople;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If it's not keyed by name then iterating is the only way to search each entry. However throwing an exception for a non-exceptional state is likely not the best way to handle a failed search. It's not unusual not to find something you're looking for-just return an empty list and handle that case through normal flow.

Comment: What's the first parameter `String` in the map? The name? Because you are NOT using it inside the `for`.

Comment: No doubt someone will suggest a streams-based solution.  You could get *terser* that way, and perhaps you would consider that more elegant.  Myself, I observe that since you're not interested in the keys at all for this purpose, it's a bit wasteful to go at the problem through the entry set.  Why not just use the `values()` collection, instead?

Comment: The fact that the OP is returning a list of `People` would indicate that they `key` is not the required entry

Comment: The Impaler, the first parameter is the ID String unique to each person that it can be found in the ID Card - It is an String because a lot of countries use numbers + letters instead of only numbers

Comment: `Optional` is better than exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution is close to optimal (except for the use of Streams). I would simplify the `for` clause as:

```
for (Person person : this.personMap.values()) {
    String name = person.getName();
    if (name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
        listOfPeople.add(person);
    }
}
```

Since you are not using the key of the map at all.

Answer (score 5):

Having thought about it a moment, it sems that *I'm* the person who's going to offer a streams-based solution.  I'm not a "do everything with streams now" kind of guy, but streams do offer a fairly easy and readable way to express some kinds of computations, and yours is one of them.  Combining that with my observation that you should work directly with the map's value collection, you get this:

```
listOfPeople = personMap.values().stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getName().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (listOfPeople.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use java Stream API.

```
personMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```